# why isnt my show/hide script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi i have a javascript script for when i click on a `img` class other images go from `invisible` to `visible` and i can keep switching between them.i have added `display:none` on the css for the images i want to show up. but nothing seems to be working

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $('img.home').click(function() {
        $('img.video && img.news && img.games && img.music').hide();
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<nav align="middle">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/video-1.png" class="video" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/news-1.png" class="news" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/logo-4.png" class="home" style="width:80px;height:80px;" onclick="$('.video' || '.news' || '.games' || 'music').toggle();" onmouseover="this.src='images/logo-4-hover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/logo-4.png';"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/games-1.png" class="games" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/music-1.png" class="music" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: .75em;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,body {
    height: 100%;
  /* new */;
}

ul {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 3px 0;
}

img.video {
    display: none;
}

img.news {
    display: none;
}

img.games {
    display: none;
}

img.music {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Pro-tip: if you want img.video, img.news, img.games, and img.music to all have some shared behavior, why not give them a shared class? If you gave them all the class `hideable` (in addition to the classes they already have), you could select all of them with `img.hideable`.

Comment: See [Multiple Selector @ jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code to

```
$('img.home').click(function() {
    $('img.video, img.news, img.games, img.music').hide();
});
```

Additionally, if you want to toggle on the images then in place of `hide()`, use `toggle()`

And also, as @Mark suggested, enclose your script within document ready block.

Comment: @Downvoter - I will be glad if you share reason too?

Comment: i used this but only the img.video image shows and the rest stays the same.

Comment: I can see an `onclick` too in markup. I hope it is not required anymore. Also, if it is required, then remove the click binding in js and update the separator from pipe to comma

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use commas instead of the && and try loading script  with document ready.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('img.home').click(function() {
     $('img.video , img.news , img.games , img.music').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i used this but when i clicked nothing worked, do i require jquery for this to work

Comment: i used this but only the img.video image shows and the rest stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the selector syntax problem which was already explained in another answers, all your images are placed inside anchor tags. You should also attach a click event handler to these anchors in order to [stop event bubbling](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/#event.stopPropagation.28.29)

This should work for you:

```
$("li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
})
$('img.home').click(function(event) {
    $('img.video , img.news , img.games , img.music').hide();
    // OR:
    // $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('img').hide();
});
```

You should also remove `onClick` attribute from the `'img.home'` element as it's unnecesary (and improperly written)

Comment: i used this but only the img.video image shows and the rest stays the same.